# Sull'uso del verbo "fungere"

Tags: word-usage, verbs

Qualche giorno fa, ho sentito parte della conversazione tra due italiani, in particolare queste frasi:

> Puoi aiutarmi con la macchina fotografica? Puoi vedere se *funge*?

L'uso del verbo "fungere" ha subito attirato la mia attenzione, dunque ne ho cercato informazioni sui dizionari. Sul [vocabolario Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/fungere/) ho trovato

> Esercitare un ufficio, per lo più a carattere provvisorio o temporaneo, o comunque adempiere una funzione che non costituisce una carica particolare: *l’assessore anziano fungeva da sindaco; f. da presidente, da segretario in una riunione; f. da padrino; f. da ufficiale di collegamento*.

E su [WordReference](http://www.wordreference.com/definizione/fungere) si può leggere:

> 1. Di persona, esercitare temporaneamente o provvisoriamente determinate funzioni: **Esempio:**
>      *il professor Mori fungerà da preside*.
> 2. Di cosa, servire per un determinato uso, genrl. diverso da quello originario: **Esempio:** *questa camera funge da ripostiglio*.

A me sembra però che gli usi di "fungere" che vengono spiegati in questi dizionari non corrispondano del tutto a quello che se ne fa nella frase della conversazione. Potreste spiegarmi qual è questo uso?

Comment: Un altro sinonimo scherzoso di _funzionare_ è _funziare_. Credo sia meno diffuso di _fungere_, però, che già è poco diffuso (come sinonimo di _funzionare_). Es.: «ma 'sto programma funzia o non funzia?»

Answer (score 7, accepted):

È un uso scherzoso, e anche piuttosto recente, di “fungere” come se fosse un sinonimo di “funzionare”. Non è però ben attestato e penso che nella stragrande maggioranza dei casi chi lo dice sia conscio della spiritosaggine.

Noto ora che il Treccani, nella [parte relativa ai sinonimi e contrari](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/fungere_(Sinonimi-e-Contrari)/), registra anche questo uso:

> (*scherz.*) [assol., essere in grado di operare] ≈ funzionare.